# Mongoose query returning more than one result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My database structure is looking like this :

```
    {
        'name' : 'entry one'
        'project' : 
            [
                {companyName : 'a name', contactPerson : [{ work_email: 'test@test.com'}] } , 
                {companyName : 'a name1', contactPerson : [{ work_email: 'test1@test.com'}] } , 
                {companyName : 'a name2', contactPerson : [{ work_email: 'test2@test.com'}] } 
            ]
    }



    {
        'name' : 'entry 2'
        'project' : 
            [
                {companyName : 'another name', contactPerson : [{ work_email: 'testing@test.com'}] } , 
                {companyName : 'another name1', contactPerson : [{ work_email: 'testing1@test.com'}] } , 
                {companyName : 'another name 2', contactPerson : [{ work_email: 'testing2@test.com'}] } 
            ]
    }
```

What i want is to find the companyName that belongs to a given work_email. So if the work_email is `test@test.com` the company name that should be returned should be `'a name'`

So the query i built with mongoose is this :

```
const projects = await ClientManagers.findOne({'project.contactPerson.work_email' : 'test@test.nl'} , 'project.companyName');
```

But this is returning all company names (from entry one) not the single one i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering will always return whole document. You need to use projection to "reshape" it. You can consider [the $ (projection) operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

```
const projects = await ClientManagers.findOne({'project.contactPerson.work_email' : 'test@test.nl'} , { 'project.$': 1 });
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SHH-F_I7qq_)

Comment: isnt it `project.$.companyName`? because he just wants the name

Comment: This is super helpful i didn't know about this yet , thank you so much

Comment: @Ifaruki yeah i can do that last step myself , thankfully !

Comment: Is it possible to update the found entry ? Let's say i want to change the companyName of the found entry. How would i do this ? Or is there an article or something you can redirect me to.

Comment: @Kevin.a sure, you can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917114/mongoose-query-deeply-nested-objects/55917180#55917180